# Memory Error in CUDA Program for Fermi GPU

Tags: cuda, gpu

I am facing the following problem on a GeForce GTX 580 (Fermi-class) GPU.

Just to give you some background, I am reading single-byte samples packed in the following manner in a file: Real(Signal 1), Imaginary(Signal 1), Real(Signal 2), Imaginary(Signal 2). (Each byte is a signed char, taking values between, -128 and 127.) I read these into a char4 array, and use the kernel given below to copy them to two float2 arrays corresponding to each signal. (This is just an isolated part of a larger program.)

When I run the program using cuda-memcheck, I get either an unqualified `unspecified launch failure`, or the same message along with `User Stack Overflow or Breakpoint Hit` or `Invalid __global__ write of size 8` at random thread and block indices.

The main kernel and launch-related code is reproduced below. *The strange thing is that this code works (and cuda-memcheck throws no error) on a non-Fermi-class GPU that I have access to. Another thing that I observed is that the Fermi gives no error for `N` less than 16384.*

```
#define N   32768

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char4 *pc4Buf_h = NULL;
    char4 *pc4Buf_d = NULL;
    float2 *pf2InX_d = NULL;
    float2 *pf2InY_d = NULL;
    dim3 dimBCopy(1, 1, 1);
    dim3 dimGCopy(1, 1);
    ...
    /* i do check for errors in the actual code */
    pc4Buf_h = (char4 *) malloc(N * sizeof(char4));
    (void) cudaMalloc((void **) &pc4Buf_d, N * sizeof(char4));
    (void) cudaMalloc((void **) &pf2InX_d, N * sizeof(float2));
    (void) cudaMalloc((void **) &pf2InY_d, N * sizeof(float2));
    ...
    dimBCopy.x = 1024;  /* number of threads in a block, for my GPU */
    dimGCopy.x = N / 1024;
    CopyDataForFFT<<<dimGCopy, dimBCopy>>>(pc4Buf_d,
                                           pf2InX_d,
                                           pf2InY_d);
    ...
}

__global__ void CopyDataForFFT(char4 *pc4Data,
                               float2 *pf2FFTInX,
                               float2 *pf2FFTInY)
{
    int i = (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x) + threadIdx.x;

    pf2FFTInX[i].x = (float) pc4Data[i].x;
    pf2FFTInX[i].y = (float) pc4Data[i].y;
    pf2FFTInY[i].x = (float) pc4Data[i].z;
    pf2FFTInY[i].y = (float) pc4Data[i].w;

    return;
}
```

<strike>One other thing I noticed in my program is that if I comment out any two char-to-float assignment statements in my kernel, there's no memory error.</strike> One other thing I noticed in my program is that if I comment out either the first two or the last two char-to-float assignment statements in my kernel, there's no memory error. If I comment out one from the first two (`pf2FFTInX`), and another from the second two (`pf2FFTInY`), errors still crop up, but less frequently. The kernel uses 6 registers with all four assignment statements uncommented, and uses <strike>5</strike> 4 registers with two assignment statements commented out.

I tried the 32-bit toolkit in place of the 64-bit toolkit, 32-bit compilation with the `-m32` compiler option, running without X windows, etc. but the program behaviour is the same.

I use CUDA 4.0 driver and runtime (also tried CUDA 3.2) on RHEL 5.6. The GPU compute capability is 2.0.

Please help! I could post the entire code if anybody is interested in running it on their Fermi cards.

<strike>UPDATE: Just for the heck of it, I inserted a `__syncthreads()` between the `pf2FFTInX` and the `pf2FFTInY` assignment statements, and memory errors disappeared for `N` = 32768. But at `N` = 65536, I still get errors.</strike> `<--` This didn't last long. Still getting errors.

UPDATE: In continuing with the weird behaviour, when I run the program using cuda-memcheck, I get these 16x16 blocks of multi-coloured pixels distributed randomly all over my screen. This does not happen if I run the program directly.

Comment: After witnessing some CUDA voodoo myself I'll suggest something that might look/be silly. Declare 2 local float2 var inside your kernel, read the values to them for x and y and then write them at once to memory. Or even try to read the char4 values to a char4 variable and from it write to the float2 variable and then to memory. What happens?

Comment: @jmsu: I tried your suggestions, but there's no difference in behaviour.

Comment: Well, no voodoo then I guess. I can only suggest that you show how you are allocating memory, maybe there is some problem with it. In the code you posted I am not seeing anything wrong.

Comment: @jmsu: Done. I've also added a few other things I tried to my question.

Comment: Well, I had once a faulty card and had that behaviour, random pixels across the screen. Go to the SDK samples folders and run some of them. For me quite some were reporting errors and test failed and one which displays that famous image of Lena just put garbage all over my screen. Returned the card and they sent me a new one. Problem solved.

Comment: Hi! did you compile for architecture 2.x?, i.e: -arch=sm_20. It will not solve your problem, but we'll want sure you compile for that architecture in order to follow your progress :). 
Regards!

Comment: @pQB: Yes, I did compile with -arch=sm_20. Thank you. But now it looks like it could be a bad card.

Comment: @jmsu: It turns out many of the SDK samples are failing on my machine too, and one of them throws up random pixel blocks all over the screen. I had a friend run this program on a different GPU (but same architecture), and he reported that it works for him. So I guess, it's a bad card. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for your card but glad I could help you track it down.

Comment: Just for the record, it _is_ a bad card. Replaced the card, and things are back to normal.

Comment: Can you report which SDK examples you tried? I think I am experiencing symptoms like you described, and I would like to try those example programs. I do already know that my CUDA4 SDK MatrixMul example fails, and my 3.2 does not, regardless whether i run the 3.2 version with CUDA3.2 or 4.0

Comment: I don't remember all the examples I tried, but I do remember that alignedTypes and matrixMul failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was a bad GPU card (see the comments).  [I'm Adding this answer to remove the question from the unanswered list and make it more useful.]

Comment: Thanks.  I want to try to get our unanswered rate down as low as possible (you can view it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/cuda/topusers)) because I want to track it as a community metric.